# "road" vs. "pavement" vs. "roadway" for French "chaussée" [road surface] in AmEng vernacular

Tags: american-english, word-usage, formality, vernacular

What's the difference between those terms? Can they be used just about interchangeably?

> road: a long, narrow stretch with a leveled or paved surface, made for traveling by motor vehicle, carriage, etc.; street or highway. [Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/road)
>
> pavement: *n.* (*Chiefly AmEng*) A hard smooth surface, especially of a public area or thoroughfare, that will bear travel. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roadway)
>
> roadway: *n.* A road, especially the part over which vehicles travel.
>   [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roadway)
>
> [**chaussée**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chauss%C3%A9e): *nf* ([**voie de circulation**](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/traffic%20lane))   road *n*; (*US*) pavement *n*; roadway *n*
>
> Il y a des nids de poule sur la chaussée, fais attention !
>    *There are potholes on the road [surface], be careful!* [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/chauss%C3%A9e)

Comment: I think pavement is mainly : 1. (Civil Engineering) a hard-surfaced path for pedestrians alongside and a little higher than a road. US and Canadian word: sidewalk. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pavement

Comment: Where I live, "pavement" is paved with macadam... so if a sidewalk is concrete or stone or dirt, it would not be called "pavement".  My dictionary says "pavement" meaning "sidewalk" is a British meaning.

Comment: I think "pavement" in your definition refers to the surface material used to make roads. http://www.aboutcivil.org/types-of-pavements.html, so in that sense it is synonymous with road.

Comment: @Josh61 - Ugh, not a fan of that quote from Collins dictionary (via TFD) in your first comment. In BrE the colloquial name for a hard-surfaced pedestrian path is indeed a pavement, and it does fall within the realm of civil engineering... but British Civil Engineers use "pavement" as a technical term (as per your more recent comment). The technical term for where pedestrians walk is Footway. Often both the carriageway and the footway are pavements.

Comment: ***Chuckhole*** is effectively unknown in BrE, and even in AmE it's about [50 times less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chuckhole%2Cpothole&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchuckhole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpothole%3B%2Cc0) than the standard ***pothole***.

Comment: Elian, you might also want to consider "asphalt" and "concrete" in your search, both of which are forms of pavement (for roadways). See for example: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-concrete-cement-and-asphalt Also, in AmerE, we use phrases like, "hit the road" (travel) and "hit the pavement" (look for a job or new clients). We also often misuse "cement" when we mean "concrete"; as in, "It used to take us all day to get from McKinleyville to Eureka and back before they laid the cement highway across the marsh."

Comment: @MarkHubbard "asphalt," "concrete," and "blacktop" are what is usually called "bitume" in French. Meaning may overlap, though, with that of "chaussée" (road surface)...

Comment: @Elian- "Concrete" is generally white, distinguishing it from *bitume,* which (I think) means asphalt (a black amalgamation that is hot-laid and softens somewhat in extremely hot weather). Asphalt and blacktop are synonymous. "Concrete is made up of three basic components: water, aggregate (rock, sand, or gravel) and Portland cement. Cement, usually in powder form, acts as a binding agent when mixed with water and aggregates. This combination, or concrete mix, will be poured and harden into the durable material with which we are all familiar." http://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete.html

Comment: @MarkHubbard Yes, "cement" is what is called "ciment" in French and is used as a building material for masonry work.

Comment: It varies from region to region, but in the US "pavement" would normally be used to refer to the material (asphalt or concrete) that is used to construct the road surface, while "roadway" would most likely be used to refer to the overall "structure", including curbs, underlayment, and pavement.

Comment: Note that if you use the word "cement" to refer to, say, the light-colored surface of an interstate highway, you will get snickers from the cognoscenti.  A road surface (or any other object) made from a combination of crushed rock, sand, and Portland cement is called "concrete".

Comment: "Asphalt", on the other  hand, while the accepted term for the common dark-colored paving material, is something of a misnomer, since true "asphalt" is a tar-like substance, and what most of us (in the US) would call "asphalt" is "asphalt concrete", a mixture of "aggregate" (rock) and "true" asphalt.  (In the UK this is known as "tarmac", which is also a misnomer, but we won't go there.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They are not quite the same.**

*Road* refers almost exclusively to something use for the travel of motor vehicles as the definition you quote says.

*Pavement* is a hard surface, almost always for travel of some kind, but sometimes other things.

For most kinds of road the terms could be used interchangeably, but there are exceptions. Let me give examples to illustrate the difference.

- A dirt road without a hard surface is a *road*, but not *pavement*.
- A hard surface used for some other purpose, even one related to travel, would be *pavement* but might not be a *road*. For example, the hard surface of a parking lot might be *pavement*, but not *road*.
- If a road has an unpaved shoulder or median, you might refer to the whole thing as a *road*, but only the main paved part as *pavement*.

*Roadway* is not common, but I would use it to refer to the parts of a road on which travel actually occurs - so excluding medians or shoulders that might be considered part of a *road*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  According to your dictionary, and my own experience: In the US, the three words are synonyms.   But, of course, in the UK "pavement" does not mean this.

Answer (score 0):

I think of it like this:

**Road:** A car travel path that has a name or a designation. Main Street is a "road", and so is Interstate 80. It's more of an abstract concept, referring to the *path* you take, rather than the physical substance of the road.

**Pavement:** The *material* that the road is physically made of, but only if that material was originally laid down as a liquid or semiliquid, like asphalt or concrete. A brick or cobblestone street isn't made of pavement, it's made of individual bricks or stones.

**Roadway:** I think this word is mostly used in legal statutes. Refers to the *place* where the travel occurs, like DJClayworth said. It's also material-agnostic, so a roadway can be made of bricks or asphalt equally well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_surface -- "pavement" refers to virtually any material used to construct a road surface.